# Getting no result back from a SELECT statement using JOINS

Tags: mysql

im trying to see the trips that goes through both station AAA and station DDD. I have 3 tables with the following columns:

1. **trip** (trip_id) (route_id) (date) (time)
2. **route** (route_id) (starting_station) (ending_station)
3. **station** (station_id) (route_id) (station_name)

I tried this query and got no result back even though I had a trip that passes though both station AAA and station DDD:

```sql
SELECT 
    trip.route_id, 
    route.starting_station, 
    route.ending_station, 
    trip.date, 
    trip.time 
FROM trip 
INNER JOIN route 
    ON route.route_id = trip.route_id 
INNER JOIN station 
    ON station.route_id = route.route_id 
WHERE trip.route_id = route.route_id 
    AND route.route_id = station.route_id 
    AND station.station_name = 'AAA' 
    AND station.station_name = 'DDD';
```

When I ask for a single station I get back a result but with 2 stations it shows no result. Can somebody help me fix this problem and tell what exactly I did wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with `station` twice since you want to set conditions on two different stations.

It should be something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    trip.route_id, 
    route.starting_station, 
    route.ending_station, 
    trip.date, 
    trip.time 

FROM trip 
INNER JOIN route
    USING (route_id)
INNER JOIN station AS station1
    USING (route_id)
INNER JOIN station AS station2
    USING (route_id)
WHERE
    station1.station_name = 'AAA' AND 
    station2.station_name = 'DDD'
```

Comment: this can not work station1.station_name = 'DDD' should be station2.station_name = 'DDD' what esle yyou need the second station table for

Comment: @nbk. Yes, there was a bug (copy-and-paste error). I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the expression

`station.station_name = 'AAA' AND station.station_name = 'DDD'`

is a paradoxical predicate - how can one station have two different names!? perhaps

`station.station_name = 'AAA' OR station.station_name = 'DDD'`

is what you were after?

Comment: The thing is with OR I get back the trips the pass through that specific station but the other one is not included in the trip so not exactly the result I was looking for from the query. lets say we have station AAA all the way to station ZZZ. Im trying to find a trip(or a bus) that passes through two different locations in this case station AAA and station DDD thats why I used AND :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).